# Trigger Push Notifications on a Flutter App with Python

Tags: python, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following scenario...

I would like to develop a Flutter app that allows to receive a push notification after a button (similar to a doorbell) has been pressed.
This button is connected to the internet.

What I have so far...

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "FireBaseMessaging.dart";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FirebaseMessagingDemo(),
    );
  }
}
```

FirebaseMessagingDemo.dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart";

class FirebaseMessagingDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  FirebaseMessagingDemo() : super();

  final String title = 'Firebase Messaging Demo';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FirebaseMessagingDemoState();
}

class _FirebaseMessagingDemoState extends State<FirebaseMessagingDemo> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  _getToken() {
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((deviceToken) {
      print("Device Token: $deviceToken");
    });
  }

  List<Message> messagesList;

  _configureFirebaseListeners() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onMessage: $message');
        _setMessage(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onLaunch: $message');
        _setMessage(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume: $message');
        _setMessage(message);
      },
    );
  }

  _setMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final notification = message['notification'];
    final data = message['data'];
    final String title = notification['title'];
    final String body = notification['body'];
    String mMessage = data['message'];
    print("Title: $title, body: $body, message: $mMessage");
    setState(() {
      Message msg = Message(title, body, mMessage);
      messagesList.add(msg);
    });
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    messagesList = List<Message>();
    _getToken();
    _configureFirebaseListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: messagesList == null ?
        0
        : messagesList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(messagesList[index].message),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}

class Message {
  String title;
  String body;
  String message;
  Message(title, body, message) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

For this purpose there is a cloud function within Firebase, which queries write operations in the Cloud Firestore and sends a push notification to the device when a new entry is made.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

var newData;
exports.myTrigger = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{messageID}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    //

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return;
    }

    var tokens = ['$$DeviceToken$$'];
    newData = snapshot.data();

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Push Title',
            body: 'Push Body',
            sound: 'default',
        },
        data: {
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            message: newData.message,
        },
    };
    try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log('Notification sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

It works so far.

My plan is that I use a Rasberry Pi to set up a button that triggers a Python script that generates an entry in the Cloud Firestore Collection and thus brings a push notification to the phone through the Cloud Function.

The only possibility I saw was to write to a realtime database, but this does not trigger the cloud function. So no possibility for me, unless the cloud function can check for changes in a realtime database.

I am open for solutions of all kind. Maybe it's possible to do it completely without cloud function or without firebase.
Or there is a possibility to write to the Cloud Firestore via Python.

I am looking forward to any kind of answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.

The `snapshot.data();` function is not available when you are operating in a realtime database environment.

You have to change the trigger function to `functions.database.ref()` and then refer for the snapshot to `snapshot.val()`, so you can get changes from a realtime database and push the data to a device.